# Finding the drag coefficient of an object from damped simple harmonic motion (spring-mass system)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, harmonic-oscillator, drag

I am currently working on an experiment to determine the relationship between the diameter of a sphere and its coefficient of drag. I will be using a spring-mass system that oscillates vertically and then damps because of drag. How can I find the coefficient of drag for the oscillating object using the data of the damping oscillation?

Comment: Please explain/define what you mean by coefficient of drag.

Comment: the drag coefficient is a dimensionless quantity that is used to quantify the drag or resistance of an object in a fluid environment, such as air or water. For example, a sphere has a drag coefficient of 0.5. I am trying to find out the drag coefficient for different objects by using a damped spring-mass system.

Comment: [Any use?}(https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2002/2002.03796.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot that will be helpful. but in the pdf you sent they are using a pendulum but in my case I am using a mass-spring system, I believe the equations will be different. thanks a lot though for taking the time to help

Comment: The decay equations will be of the same form.